# How can I report a Roblox bug?

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

How can I report Roblox bugs? I have bugs to report and what is the best way to report bugs in a way they are most likely going to be fixed. I cannot go to the dev forum because I cannot find a new thread button. Also, why can't I use the dev forum? How can I report this a bug? Or if I find a studio bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go [here](https://www.roblox.com/support) and in "Type of help category" select "Bug Report".

See also [What Should I Do If I Find a Glitch on Roblox?](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203312900-What-Should-I-Do-If-I-Find-a-Glitch-on-Roblox-).

Comment: Note: make sure you're reporting an actual Roblox problem, not a game problem. If possible, include proof that the problem occurs in multiple games. Otherwise, they'll just pass you off to the game's developer, who will blame it on Roblox, who will pass you off to the developer...